# Where can I get a copy of Mountain Lion that I can resell with my Apple hardware?

Tags: macos

I'm looking to turn over some older Apple hardware I have and all of the gear has been upgraded to the latest Mountain Lion using the App Store version of Mountain Lion and my Apple ID. Section 2.B of the [EULA for Mountain Lion](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf) makes it clear the license I purchased for Mountain Lion via the App Store is non-transferrable:

> B. Mac App Store License. If you obtained a license for the Apple Software from the Mac App Store, then subject to the terms and conditions of this License and as permitted by the Mac App Store Usage Rules set forth in the App Store Terms and Conditions (http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/ww/) (“Usage Rules”), you are granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license

Where can I obtain a transferrable license for Mountain Lion? I don't see any way to buy Mountain Lion outside of the App Store. Do Apple Stores carry Mountain Lion on DVD or USB thumb drives? I see no mention of this on their Canadian store web site.

I have Snow Leopard DVDs for these machines, but having them running Mountain Lion makes them more attractive resale units.

Comment: I just got off a chat with the US store's live chat and they told me I could call 1-800-MY-APPLE and order physical Mountain Lion media and license. It's the first I heard and I'm hesitant to call just to not buy. Have you tried calling the canadian online store to see if this might be something new that Apple is offering? It might be a new person that heard Apple can send 10.6 media to potential Mountain Lion upgraders, but if it's true this is the first I've heard of Mountain Lion being for sale physically.

Comment: It's a hike to store (hence the question) and didn't even think to call the number but I will now!

Comment: Related: [Reinstall Mac OS X Mountain Lion before selling a Mac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/70625/7833)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not at all clear that Apple will endorse the transference of an App Store account and it's clear they don't endorse transferring parts of the purchase history. Legally, you might be able to get away with this in certain parts of the world, but it's clearly not something Apple is keen to point out how to accomplish this or has built in a "gift my license" functionality to their stores at present.

Why not include a gift card for the App Store in question or some other cash equivalent with the sale?

Comment: The gift card option is a nice idea. I'd really just like to have fresh ML on it though. An immediate OS upgrade is a bit of sticking point with the less savvy potential buyer.

Comment: I've loaded OS to save time and sat with someone to help them set up their Apple ID and ensured they redeemed the card. I've also gifted them the purchase to the Apple ID of their choice so that I've felt good that what I was selling was properly licensed. You could even wipe it and leave things with a Recovery HD but no OS if none of the above seems workable in your specific instance.

Comment: That's a great idea, giving them the tech support with it.

Comment: I have a good relationship with my local Apple stores and they have never once refused me using their store as a public meeting place to sell a used Mac. I tell the buyer they can take the mac to the genuis bar and get an opinion on the repair history and another opinion before they pay me. The store likes to meet customers and they can shop accessories, learn about classes and hopefully everyone wins on the transaction. If your store is crazy busy, keep things short but if you ask before using you should be OK in most cases.

Comment: Wow. I never even considered doing that. I need to hang around my local Apple store more often!