# Running Time Mechine Backup from Recovery HD

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, recovery-hd

My MacBook seems to be getting kernel panics when booting up. I've decided to create a backup, reinstall OS X, and restore from the backup. But I can't create a Time Machine backup because I unable to boot into the main partition.

My question is: how do I run Time Machine from the Recovery HD, you can only restore. I've also tried `tmutil`, but the terminal does not want to run anything from the other partition.

Comment: Have you tried just reinstalling OS X without wiping your HD? That solved my kernel panic problem, no Time Machine backup/restore necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Recovery HD doesn't have the ability to make a backup other than using Disk Utility or the terminal app to copy files.

If you have a spare HD available or don't want to risk reinstalling the OS (which isn't designed to delete any user files - but could if there is directory damage) I would say go buy a USB external drive and reformat it as GUID/Mac and use Disk Utility to "restore" the boot drive to the external drive. Then you can run the OS installer from Recovery or erase and install.

- [Reinstall Mac OS X Mountain Lion before selling a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70625/reinstall-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-before-selling-a-mac)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904